# How to intercept controller methods in Spring MVC and fiddle with passed parameters?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, parameters

How can I intercept controller methods in Spring MVC and fiddle around with the given parameters passed by the Spring framework?

**Example**

```
@PostMapping(consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public ResponseEntity<?> createPerson( CreatePersonCommand command ) {

   // ...
}
```

I want to be able to fiddle with the command object **before my createPerson** method is called. Lets say, because I want to set additional parameters (e.g. timestamp,...)

**Update:**

I am aware of the HandlerIntercaptor & Adapter. However, I still dont know how can I fiddle around with the **CreatePersonCommand object** in the **preHandle** Method.

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(
    HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler )
    throws Exception {

    // FIDDLE WITH CreatePersonCommand ???

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Spring you could use aspects, and easy example for your case would be this:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class PreHandlerAspect {
    
    @Before("execution(* com.your.controller..*Controller.*(..))")
    public void beforeController(JoinPoint joinPoint){
        //Here your code
        //You could access to the request, parameters, add the aspect for just 1 controller, many,...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I was hoping that Spring MVC has more like a out-of-a-box solution. I will play with Aspects then :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Interceptors, method `preHandle()`:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/

**Update:**
I don't know how to do it exactly but you can try to use your handler object:

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler){
  ((HandlerMethod)handler).getMethodParameters()...
}
```

Let me know your final solution :)

Comment: @Niki I started to play with the handler in the exact way already but it seems that the method "getMethodParameters" leads to Java reflection which cannot get the actual parameter value. But I have to dig more!

Comment: @Niki I have implemented the solution as an Aspect. Its working like a charm! :)

Comment: Great :) I will try it too when I have time